# Prove set must be a member of another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have this question regarding sets:

> Consider a set, S. Also, consider a set, A, whose elements, E, are
>   subsets of S subject to the following rules:
>
> - A is non-empty
> - A is closed under complements, i.e:
>
>   ```
>   E ∈ A ⇒ E' ∈ A,    where the complement of E is the set of elements of S which are not in E.
>   ```
> - A is closed under union of the sets which make up its elements, i.e:
>
>   ```
>   E1, .., Ei, .., En ∈ A ⇒ (union n i=1)Ei ∈ A,
>   ```
>
>   where the notation to the right of the implication means the union
>     of all     elements Ei.
>
> For example, for S = {a, b, c, d} we could have A = {∅, {a, b}, {c,
>   d}, {a, b, c, d}}, but not A = {∅, {a, b}, {a, b, c, d}}, due to the
>   second rule. The element (set) {a, b} is the complement of {c, d}.
>
> **Prove the following.** The first two use only the rules from above. The last proof has been started for you and uses an extension of a
>   relation from the lectures as well as the above rule(s).
>
> (a) S must be a member of A.
>
> (b) Hence, or otherwise, the empty set must be a member of A.
>
> (c) A is closed under intersection of the sets which make up its
>   elements, i.e.: E1, .., Ei, .., En ∈ A ⇒ (intersection n, i=1)Ei ∈ A,
>   where the notation is similar to that for the third rule.

So far I haven't even been able to get part a).
This is what I have come up with so far:

a) Since ∃E. E∈S. E∈A ↔ E'∈A
   We can say S = E union E' ∈ A
   Thus S ∈ A

Does this make any sense?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You explanation of A is exactly correct and perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for part (a) seems perfectly fine. In words, we know by the first rule that $A$ contains some element $E$; we know by the second rule that $A$ contains its complement $E'$; we know by the third rule that $A$ contains their union $E \cup E'$. Since $E'$ contains all elements of $S$ not in $E$, $E \cup E'$ contains all elements of $S$, so $E \cup E' = S$.

You can do part (b) by the same method, or you can use the first part (that $S \in A$) as a shortcut to show that $\varnothing \in A$.

For part (c), the key thing to remember is De Morgan's law: $(E_1 \cup E_2)' = E_1' \cap E_2'$.

Comment: Ah thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

a) your explanation is perfect.

b) Well if $S \in A$ then $S^c \in A$ and ....

c) If $S \in A$ and $R \in A$ can we express $R \cap S$ somehow in terms of complements and unions only... in such a way that that assures it is a member of $A$.  Hint: Have you ever heard of [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)?

Comment: Great wasn't sure if my explanation was right! Think I should be able to make a good attempt at completing it now, thanks :)